# c# combobox displaying arraylist items

Tags: c#

I want my combo box to list all my array list items. This is what i have so far but i don't know what i can add to make it display each array list item into the combo box.
Is there a way i can write Items.Display  or something along those lines?

```
public void eh()
{
snip
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `cboActor.Items.Add(line);`?

Comment: the cbActor must have a property called DataSource just assign the cboActor.DataSource = ActorArrayList and see wat happens..

Comment: Can you provide more information/tagson frameworks used like WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void PopulateActors()
{
    cboActor.Items.Clear(); 
    cboActor.Items.AddRange(ActorArrayList.Cast<string>());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataSource` to bind the `ArrayList` to your combobox:

```
yourComboBox.DataSource = yourArrayList;
```

Use `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to select what is displayed and what is evaluated as `Value` of the item:

```
yourComboBox.DisplayMember = "Displayed thing";
youtComboBox.ValueMember = "Evaluated thing";
```

If you don't specify the `DisplayMember`, the `ToString()` will be called on each item to get the displayed string instead. In your case, it looks like you have an `ArrayList` of string, so you don't need to specify any values for `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.

**NOTE**: You should use a `List<T>` instead, it would be better. `ArrayList` is just an old stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array list like this

```
ArrayList sampleArray = new ArrayList();
            sampleArray.Add("India");
            sampleArray.Add("China");
            sampleArray.Add("USA");
            sampleArray.Add("UK");
            sampleArray.Add("Japan");
```

and then can add it to your combobox

```
cboActor.Items.Clear(); 
 cboActor.Items.AddRange(sampleArray.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ComboBoxItems in a loop and add them one by one:

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = "Item text1";
item.Value = 12;

cboActor.Items.Add(item);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string line in ActorArrayList)
{
    cboActor.Items.Add(line);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a listItem(Text,Value)

```
foreach (Actor line in ActorArrayList)
    {
        cboActor.Items.Add(new ListItem( line.Name ,line.ID)); //as second part you may enter the ID of the object so you can use it at a later time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example not mentioned above! Similar to Sid M, since that didn't work for me, I share the solution I found for me:

```
String[] data = new String[]{"Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4"};

cboData.Items.AddRange(data);
```